# Show $\dfrac{g(z)-g(z_0)}{z-z_0}-f(z_0)\to 0$ as $z\to z_0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ - continuous. Define 
$$g(z)=\int_\rho^z f(\zeta)\,d\zeta$$ where $z\in\Omega$. Show for all $z\in\Omega$
$$\dfrac{g(z)-g(z_0)}{z-z_0}-f(z_0)\to 0$$ as $z\to z_0$

**Proof:** 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
g(z)-g(z_0) & 
= \int_\rho^z f(\zeta)\,d\zeta - \int_\rho^{z_0} f(\zeta)\,d\zeta  = \int_{z_0}^z f(\zeta)\,d\zeta
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

But from here I am unsure what to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is ${\mit Ω} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ or ${\mit Ω} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: $\Omega\subset \mathbb{C}$

Comment: Then what do you mean by $z \geqslant z_0$?

Comment: Just the case when $z$ is greater than $z_0$

Comment: What does "greater than" mean for a complex number, @UsernameUnknown?\

Comment: Ok I see why that is wrong but I should still get $\int_{z_0}^z f(\zeta)\,d\zeta$

Comment: The question is very imprecise. Integral from $\rho$ to z has to be defined precisely after mentioning connectedness of $\Omega$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is almost the same as in the real-variable case. Notice that

$$f(z_0) = \frac{1}{z - z_0} \int_{z_0}^z f(z_0) \, d\zeta$$

and so after a simplification, the difference becomes

$$\frac{1}{z - z_0} \int_{z_0}^z f(\zeta) - f(z_0) \, d\zeta.$$

Now the integrand tends to zero due to continuity, and the overall limit is zero.

Comment: I think there might be error with your first equation

Comment: No, the first equation is correct. Why do you think there is an error?

Comment: How can you have $f(z_0)$ on both sides?

Comment: Well, why *can't* you? Try computing the integral on the right hand side. $f(z_0)$ is just a fixed complex number.

Comment: Oh I see it. I was just overlooking it. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Placing a constant inside an integral like this is a *very* common technique for introducing cancellation.